Adding a dynamic url in vue.js with hubspot HubDB tables
I am trying to pull in the table url into a case study item but its showing the url as undefined.
The bit of code I need help with
:href="'/'+item.case_study_url">

How do I pull in the db url into hubspot?
I have a table in hubspot and then vue.js pulling in the url?

Very unclear as of what you want to achieve here. What is inside of item.case_study_url? Why do you want to wire a DB url into Vue? How it it related to a CRM?

I'm trying to pull in the url from the hubspot hubdb database into a case study page

I have a hubdb db with a field called url and this has a column name: case_study_url and then I'm trying the pass this url into a case study page:




                                        <img class="h-100 w-100 object-fit-cover" :src="item.card_image
I am not familiar with Hubspot, do you maybe have a docs page for such a thing? What kind of resource is supposed to be there? Also, is it supposed to be a public DB access? Does it work in a regular HTML file? Do you want to integrate the DB somehow on a front-end page or have a link to that endpoint? Please do not post code here but rather update your question with code snippets. What's inside of slicedCaseStudies (besides the sliced part)?

computed: {
slicedCaseStudies() {
return this.filteredCaseStudies.slice(0, this.limit);
}
}

The slicedCaseStudies is a file called case-studies-app.js which is shown in the code above

Please take some time to provide a proper [repro] explaining your issue properly, rather than sharing some pieces of code in the comments.
